# react-native init error file not found?

Tags: npm, react-native

I try to get into the [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) of React Native but I am stuck at init a new project. A npm error occurs `npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.staging/xtend-ea557a9c3da42553dd204c5fe8fb762c/package.json'`

Here is the log:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-vikti:dev vikti$ react-native init AwesomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject
AwesomeProject@0.0.1 /Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject
├── absolute-path@0.0.0  extraneous
├── archive-type@3.0.1  extraneous
├── babel-core@5.8.21  extraneous
├── beeper@1.1.0  extraneous
├── bl@1.0.0  extraneous
├── bser@1.0.0  extraneous
├── buffer-to-vinyl@1.0.1  extraneous
├── caw@1.1.0  extraneous
├── chokidar@1.2.0  extraneous
├── cli-table@0.3.1  extraneous
├── commondir@1.0.1  extraneous
├── connect@2.8.3  extraneous
├── cross-spawn@2.0.0  extraneous
├── dargs@4.0.1  extraneous
├── dateformat@1.0.11  extraneous
├── detect-conflict@1.0.0  extraneous
├── diff@1.4.0  extraneous
├── each-async@1.1.1  extraneous
├── ejs@2.3.4  extraneous
├── errno@0.1.4  extraneous
├── filenamify@1.2.0  extraneous
├── findup-sync@0.2.1  extraneous
├── github-username@2.0.0  extraneous
├── glob-watcher@0.0.8  extraneous
├── glob2base@0.0.12  extraneous
├── globby@2.1.0  extraneous
├── got@4.2.0  extraneous
├── grouped-queue@0.3.0  extraneous
├── gruntfile-editor@1.0.0  extraneous
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2  extraneous
├── html-wiring@1.2.0  extraneous
├── image-size@0.3.5  extraneous
├── immutable@3.7.5  extraneous
├── inquirer@0.8.5  extraneous
├── is-bzip2@1.0.0  extraneous
├── is-gzip@1.0.0  extraneous
├── is-tar@1.0.0  extraneous
├── is-url@1.2.1  extraneous
├── is-zip@1.0.0  extraneous
├── istextorbinary@1.0.2  extraneous
├── joi@5.1.0  extraneous
├── lodash._reescape@3.0.0  extraneous
├── lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0  extraneous
├── lodash.template@3.6.2  extraneous
├── log-symbols@1.0.2  extraneous
├── module-deps@3.5.6  extraneous
├── multimatch@2.0.0  extraneous
├── multipipe@0.1.2  extraneous
├── nopt@3.0.4  extraneous
├── optimist@0.6.1  extraneous
├── ordered-read-streams@0.1.0  extraneous
├── pretty-bytes@2.0.1  extraneous
├── progress@1.1.8  extraneous
├── promise@7.0.4  extraneous
├── react-timer-mixin@0.13.3  extraneous
├── react-tools@0.14.0-beta1  extraneous (git://github.com/facebook/react.git#b4e74e38e43ac53af8acd62c78c9213be0194245)
├── rebound@0.0.12  extraneous
├── regenerator@0.8.36  extraneous
├── rimraf@2.4.3  extraneous
├── run-async@0.1.0  extraneous
├── sane@1.3.0  extraneous
├── seek-bzip@1.0.5  extraneous
├── shelljs@0.5.3  extraneous
├── sinon@1.17.1  extraneous
├── stacktrace-parser@0.1.3  extraneous
├── stat-mode@0.2.1  extraneous
├── strip-dirs@1.1.1  extraneous
├── text-table@0.2.0  extraneous
├── uglify-js@2.4.16  extraneous
├── underscore@1.7.0  extraneous
├── underscore.string@3.2.2  extraneous
├── untildify@2.1.0  extraneous
├── vinyl@0.4.6  extraneous
├── vinyl-assign@1.2.1  extraneous
├── vinyl-file@1.2.1  extraneous
├── ware@1.3.0  extraneous
├── wordwrap@1.0.0  extraneous
├── ws@0.8.0  extraneous
├── xdg-basedir@2.0.0  extraneous
├── yauzl@2.3.1  extraneous
├── yeoman-assert@2.1.0  extraneous
└── yeoman-welcome@1.0.1  extraneous

npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/vikti/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/Users/vikti/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5
npm ERR! path /Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.staging/xtend-ea557a9c3da42553dd204c5fe8fb762c/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.staging/xtend-ea557a9c3da42553dd204c5fe8fb762c/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/vikti/dev/AwesomeProject/npm-debug.log
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: I just posted an issue on github. It seems to be a better place. But I will post an answer when it will be resolved.

Comment: Finally!!
1)Removed nvm
2)installed node via homebrew 
3)clean npm cache

I don't know why but it works! (I bet on the cache clean)

Comment: (1) sudo npm cache clean -f
(2) sudo npm install -g n
(3) sudo n stable
(4) brew install node it's fixed the issue.  This is from Grevioushead answer here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3239